# Bash parameter expansion on variable with multiple spaces

Tags: bash

Let's assume the following variable:

```
something="    abc   def      ghi"
```

I'm trying to use parameter expansion and leave out only the `abc`. I've tried 10 combinations that made sense and 20 more randomly. The closest I got is the following:

```
echo ${something% *}
abc def
```

Is it possible for this to work out? If so, how? Thanks.

Comment: Could this question not be rephrased as _"extract first word from bash variable"_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's going to be tough in a single bash-expansion. You might be interested in this:

```
$ a="    abc   def      ghi"
$ [[ "${a}" =~ ([^\ ][^\ ]*) ]]
$ echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
```

This essentially searches for all *words* in the string and stores them in the array `BASH_REMATCH`. More information in `man bash` section `[[ expression ]]`.

You can also convert things into an array:

```
$ a="    abc   def      ghi"
$ b=( $a )
$ echo "${b[0]}"
```

Or you can use `read`

```
$ a="    abc   def      ghi"
$ read -r b dummy <<< "${a}"
$ echo "${b}"
```

But if you really want to use parameter expansion, and you allow the usage of `extglob` and you do not know the number of words there are in the string, you can do

```
$ a="    abc   def      ghi"
$ shopt -s extglob
$ a=${a##*([ ])}   #remove the spaces in the front
$ a=${a%% *}       #remove everything from the first space onwards
$ echo "${a}"
```

Comment: Some great and creative suggestions in the whole thread, I think this is the most extensive answer through.

Answer (score 2):

If the string `def` is know upfront, you can use bash pattern substitution:

```
echo ${something/ def*/}
```

That's replacing everything after `def` by nothing.

You could also use the following if the string `def` is in the variable `a`:

```
a="def"
echo ${something/ ${a}*/}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's just the first whitespace-delimited word you want, use `read`.

```
read x _ <<< "${something}"
```

`read` takes the value of `"${something}"`, and splits it into two words based on the current value of `IFS`; the first word (`abc`) is assigned to `x`, with the second word (consisting of all remains characters) assigned to the throwaway variable `_`.

Comment: Is `$_` really throw-away? It's documented as doing a number of things at the bottom of ***Special Parameters*** in the man page, and has different uses in different contexts. I'm pretty sure it was throw-away in POSIX shell, but in bash ... perhaps not so much.

Comment: It's throwaway in the sense that you don't intend to use the value. Even if you assign to it explicitly, the shell still does its normal assignment to it afterward.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in a single parameter expansion, instead, do this :

```
$ x=${something% def*}
$ echo ${x# *}
abc
```

Comment: Ah, I assumed it can't be done in a single parameter expansion. If you mention that in your comment I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks, I can mark it as correct in 3 more mins - will check back in a bit. :P

Comment: note that `${x# *}` actually removes only one blank at the start of the string and again the shell wordsplitting does the rest. might as well have left that part out.

Answer (score 1):

With extglob

```
shopt -s extglob
echo ${something%%*( )*([^ ])*( )*([^ ])}
```

The substitution itself does not cut the leading blanks though, the shell word splitting does that. if you quote the argument to echo they will still be there.

The substitution removes the longest possible match for zero or more spaces followed by zero or more characters that are not spaces, followed again by zero or more spaces and zero or more not-spaces at the end of the string.